# Using faces in call to action buttons, good or bad?

Tags: call-to-action

We have a client who is pretty set in using images of her staff on call to action buttons. I can see how it would build trust for the user to see a face since their service involves speaking to someone to get a custom quote.

Currently they have such button:
[image]

The down side as a developer is that I have to work around these images in the buttons and does not allow buttons to be easily changed going forward.

Does anyone know of any stats or articles that talk bout this type of thing so I can get a clear answer as to what is going to be the best call to action.

Thanks

Comment: There's probably some fallacy / circular-reasoning going on here. "*People are drawn to pictures of faces, people also click buttons so if we put faces on our buttons then people will click them"*. I see no actual connection between why a face on a button makes it more clickable. Indeed it runs the risk of being *less* noticed as it could be thought of as an advert and subconsciously avoided altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used a face *as* a button, but one of the marketing methods we learned in college was to use people's images to direct attention to a particular call to action link/button. What was particularly effective was an image of the face of a child turned slightly with the button in the eye line of the child. The "what's that cute kid looking at?" is hard for us to ignore subconsciously. [Here is an article with some eyetracking data that supports this hypothesis](http://usableworld.com.au/2009/03/16/you-look-where-they-look/).

http://uxmovement.com/buttons/call-to-action-buttons-best-practices-guide/ has a good piece on different methods for creating CTAs, and while there is mention of icons, they don't say anything about pictures.

https://www.2checkout.com/blog/article/3-ways-to-optimize-your-call-to-action-buttons has more good info about using arrows to direct your attention to a link/button.

I'd stay away from using a face as a button, but would try to find a way to incorporate them into the design to direct attention to the button.

Comment: I've added in a link to your answer about the 'what's the cute kid looking at' as it has some eyetracking evidence. I hope that covers off what you were referring to there.

Answer (score 2):

The call to action with human faces are frequently used for online help buttons:
[image]
The reason is more to some skeuomorphic intentions, rather in deep psychology background. Indeed, they try to convey the idea of a real person is ready and glad) to communicate with a user.

Digging more in psychology side, you can refer to [100 Things Every Designer Needs to Know About People](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321767535) by S. Weinschenk. Takeaways are:

> - People recognize and react to faces on Web pages faster than anything    else on the  page (at least by those who are not
>     autistic).
> - Faces looking right at people will have the greatest emotional impact on a    Web page,  probably because the eyes are the most
>     important part of    the face.
> - If a face on a Web page looks at another spot or product on    the page, people will also  tend to look at that product.  This    doesn’t
>     necessarily mean that they paid attention to  it, just that    they
>     physically looked at it.